# How to make a toast and then change the screen at the same button click ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, toast

I am trying to show a toast when the user hits the register button and then direct the user to the login screen as follows:

```
  print("Registration Successful")
  self.view.makeToast("Registration Successful")
  let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

But the problem here is that screen changes quickly due to which the toast can hardly be read. I would like to show the "Successful" toast and then change the screen. Can someone help me with it.

Comment: You can push ViewController after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.view.hideToast()
    let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, iOS does not support toasts, so you must be using some kind of a library. I guess it does not support completion handlers, so the most straight forward thing to do is to wait for a moment and then present the next view controller.

```
// it waits for 3 seconds and then presents the next view controller
let delay = Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), {() -> Void in
 let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
view.makeToast(message: "Success", duration: 2, position: HRToastPositionCenter, title: "Success")
                let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 2 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
                dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                     }
```